# Pandas: Create MultiIndex / groupby using existing index and column headers

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm trying to take a 2-dimensional data frame and turn it into a (more-or-less) one-dimensional data frame where an existing column is used as the first level index and the column headers are used as the second level index.

I've been trying `.melt()`, `.groupby()`, `.transpose()`, `.MultiIndex()`, `.pivot()`... all without any luck - I think mainly to do with the fact that they need to be combined in some way that eludes me.

**Setup:**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO(u'''
AXIS    A       B       C       D
X       100     101     102     103 
Y       200     201     202     203
Z       300     301     302     303
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, delim_whitespace = True)
```

**Desired Output:**

```
                Num
One     Two     
  X       A     100
  X       B     101
  X       C     102
  X       D     103
  Y       A     200
  Y       B     201
  Y       C     202
  Y       D     203
  Z       A     300
  Z       B     301
  Z       C     302
  Z       D     303
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, `set_index`, `stack`, and `reset_index`:

```
df.set_index('AXIS').stack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   AXIS level_1    0
0     X       A  100
1     X       B  101
2     X       C  102
3     X       D  103
4     Y       A  200
5     Y       B  201
6     Y       C  202
7     Y       D  203
8     Z       A  300
9     Z       B  301
10    Z       C  302
11    Z       D  303
```

And, you can do some housekeeping with rename columns resetting index etc...

```
df.set_index('AXIS').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'AXIS':'one','level_1':'two',0:'num'}).set_index(['one','two'])
```

Output:

```
         num
one two     
X   A    100
    B    101
    C    102
    D    103
Y   A    200
    B    201
    C    202
    D    203
Z   A    300
    B    301
    C    302
    D    303
```

Comment: Wow, I rattle off a list of functions I used... and missed a very simple one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I like this for speed

```
i = df.AXIS.values
c = np.array(list('ABCD'))
v = np.column_stack([df[col].values for col in c])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [i.repeat(c.size), np.tile(c, i.size)],
    names=['One', 'Two']
)
# Or this for brevity
# idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([i, c], names=['One', 'Two'])
pd.DataFrame(v.ravel(), idx, ['Num'])

         Num
One Two     
X   A    100
    B    101
    C    102
    D    103
Y   A    200
    B    201
    C    202
    D    203
Z   A    300
    B    301
    C    302
    D    303
```

Comment: thanks @piRSquared - when you say "speed" are you saying that method is faster (processing time) than the other answers provided?  I see a list comprehension in there and always cringe at the native python... but that could be an unwarranted reaction.

Comment: @pshep123 that is an unwarranted reaction.  comprehensions are usually very fast and usually faster than an equivalent `for` loop.... I tested that comprehension versus `df.iloc[:, 1:].values` and the comprehension + `np.column_stack` is much faster.  At least over smaller data sets.  I haven't tested over a larger one yet.

Comment: Simple and elegant ! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#Using pd.melt to convert columns to rows.
pd.melt(df.rename(columns={'AXIS':'ONE'}),id_vars='ONE', var_name='TWO', value_name='Num').set_index(['ONE','TWO']).sort_index()
Out[28]: 
         Num
ONE TWO     
X   A    100
    B    101
    C    102
    D    103
Y   A    200
    B    201
    C    202
    D    203
Z   A    300
    B    301
    C    302
    D    303
```

Comment: Allen, thanks for this, but @ScottBoston's is a little cleaner.  Going to accept that one.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected the trick is in combining the correct id and value variables

```
 pd.melt(df, id_vars=['AXIS'], value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']).sort_values(['AXIS'])
```

Comment: gnub - thanks, but this sorts in order of `['A','B','C','D']`, not `['X','Y','Z']`

Comment: @pshep123 I have added the sorting of the dataframe using variable `AXIS`